# Differentiating an Integral of $f(x,t)$

Tags: integration

How would I do the following calculation?

$$ \frac{d}{dx}( \int_0^x{(x-t)f^{''}(t)dt}) $$

I tried it and I got $f^{'}(x)$, but I don't think I did it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_0^x{(x-t)f^{''}(t)dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dx} x \int_0^x f^{''}(t)dt - \frac{d}{dx}  \int_0^x tf^{''}(t)dt=\dots\,. $$

Can you finish it?

**Added:** write

$$ g(x) = \int_0^x f^{''}(t)dt $$

in the above equation and then you need to use the product rule.

**Note:**

> $$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x h(t) dt = h(x).$$

Comment: Using your start I got $f^{''}(x)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @PaulMalinowski: Take your time to work out the problem. You should get $\int_{0}^{x} f''(t) dt$ which you can integrate and simplify.

Comment: ah of course. so it's $f^{'}(x)-f^{'}(0)$.  Thank You!

Comment: @PaulMalinowski: You are welcome.